# How to reference third party library stored in a different dll

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-assembly

I have a project that loads in an assembly over the net, this remotely loaded assembly contains all the business logic and UI code.

I want this assembly to remain small and have bigger third party libraries like MahApps stored in the base program.

My remote assembly tries to load resources as follows:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
```

After using ILMerge to merge MahApps.Metro into the base program, it appears that at runtime (after loading the remote assembly) it tries to look for the resources within BaseProgram.g.resources instead of MahApps.Metro.g.resources, resulting in exceptions of 'cannot locate resource'. Does ILMerge not play nice with WPF?

I then tried using [Fody.Costura](https://github.com/Fody/Costura) to embed MahApps.Metro as a resource in BaseProgram instead, but the remote assembly can still not find the resources.

Does anyone have an idea how I should be bundling MahApps.Metro and how I should reference it from a consumer assembly?

Comment: This looks correct. Are you doing anything with AppDomains?

Comment: Yes I have an AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve handler, I return the executing assembly (BaseProgram.dll) on requests for MahApps.Metro, but for some reason it cannot locate the resources for MahApps.Metro in the merged assembly.